# react: использование или не использование состояния в функциональном компоненте

Tags: reactjs, компоненты, usestate

Теоретический вопрос (не очень улавливаю различия).

Есть компонент:

```
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
    [data] = useState(() => prepareData());
    return <></>;
}
```

Вопрос:

В каких случаях **НУЖНО ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ** состояние без функции его изменения (как в примере выше) и вариант:

```
const MyComponent = (props: MyComponentProps) => {
    const data = prepareData();
    return <></>;
}
```

будет неподходящим?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вам интересно, когда нужно использовать state, а когда обычные переменные. В таком случае разница будет в том, что при изменении state, React автоматически перерисует компонент, чтобы отобразить новые данные. Обычные переменные такого функционала не имеют

Comment: Но стоит отметить, что если вы используете просто переменную, то она перезапишется при перерендере. То есть если там идет запрос куда-то, при каждом перерендере будет происходить запрос.

Comment: Только примеры какие-то вообще не равнозначные... В первом `data` - функция. А во втором она уже результат работы функции... Паритетная запись `const data = () => prepareData();`

Comment: @Listopad02, но раз я делаю `count data = ...;`, то изменение переменной не предполагается и будет выполнено однократно при инициализации, разве не так?

Comment: @Zhihar (про втарой вариант)нет, не так. Каждый раз при перересовке будет вызвана preparData(), и даже любое изменение внутри компонента связанная со state тоже перезапустит функцию.

Comment: @Zhihar также первый вариант это про другое, если вдруг внутри prepereData есть очень сложная логика и data не будет поподать в поле зрение пользователя то только тогда имеет смысл так писать. Скажем так с таким синтексисом prepareData будет вызвана в момент когда data окажится в поле зрения пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Функциональный компонент представляет из себя просто функцию рендера.

Соответственно, при каждом рендере выполняется данная функция.

При вызове каждый раз создаются и инициализируются локальные переменные. В Случае с

```
const data = prepareData();
```

функция prepareData будет вызываться каждый раз.

Если нужно сохранить состояние между вызовами функции и используется хук `useState`.

В случае с

```
const [data] = useState(() => prepareData());
```

функция prepareData вызовется только в первый раз, далее будет возвращаться значение.